# custom Datagrid MUI pagination

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have been implemented a custom `select` to jump from one page to another, together with the arrows to scroll pages one by one, but somehow I get : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'). or : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')

I saw this code somewhere, but I am not sure that "onPreviousPageClick" and "onNextPageClick" are `TablePaginationActions`'s props.
Anyone did implemented custom pagination like this one?
Where could be the mistake?

```
const CustomPagination = (props) => {
return (
  <GridPagination
    ActionsComponent={(innerProps) => (
      <>
        <IconButton onClick={innerProps.onPreviousPageClick} disabled={!innerProps.hasPreviousPage}>
          <NavigateBeforeIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Select value={innerProps.page} onChange={innerProps.onPageChange}>
          {Array.from({ length: totalPages }, (_, index) => index + 1).map((page) => (
            <MenuItem key={page} value={page}>
              {page}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
        <IconButton onClick={innerProps.onNextPageClick} disabled={!innerProps.hasNextPage}>
          <NavigateNextIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </>
    )}
    {...props}
  />
);
};
```